# OData in ASP.NET 5 and MVC 6 : searching for ODataFunction route alternative in ASP.NET 5 and MVC 6

Tags: asp.net-mvc, odata, asp.net-core

I am converting my project from ASP.NET 4 and MVC 5 to ASP.NET 5 and MVC 6. I have implemented OData in my old project. I started using the source given at

https://github.com/OData/WebApi/tree/vNext

I have include the sample project and the project "Microsoft.AspNet.OData" available there.

I am trying to implement, ODataRoute as shown in below code

```
[HttpGet]
[ODataRoute("GetSalesTaxRate(PostalCode={postalCode})")]
public IHttpActionResult GetSalesTaxRate([FromODataUri] int postalCode)
{
    double rate = 5.6;  // Use a fake number for the sample.
    return Ok(rate);
}
```

to be able to call the function using syntax like

```
GET http://localhost:38479/GetSalesTaxRate(PostalCode=10) HTTP/1.1
```

I didnt find the ODataRoute in that code. can someone tell me how to achieve similar functionality using latest OData package in ASP.NET 5

Comment: Do you actually need functionality from vNext? If not, you should be using the latest release package on [NuGet.org](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.OData/).

Comment: do you have any reference example for this..i noticed that even after including this package, few things doesnt works..like i didnt find AddOdata method, or useOdata method.

Comment: `AddOData` and `UseOData` are methods exclusive to vNext.

Comment: isnt vnext and asp.net,mvc not same.

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare the OData function as part of your model builder configuration.

```
ODataModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();

builder.Function("GetSalesTaxRate")
    .Returns<double>()
    .Parameter<int>("PostalCode");
```

Comment: just asking again..dont i need to give ODataRoute attribute. i see that in my old mvc 5, app i had both it in both as a part of model builder and also as route..i hope you are talking about the ASP.net 5 and MVC6

Comment: Yes, you still need to specify the route as you did in your sample code. The function you are trying to implement is documented in [Actions and Functions in OData v4 Using ASP.NET Web API 2.2](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-v4/odata-actions-and-functions) under "Example: Adding an Unbound Function".

Comment: these odata function options are not available in latest asp.net 5 and mvc6

Comment: OData is not built-in to ASP.NET. You need to add the `Microsoft.AspNet.OData` package to your project. Get it from [NuGet.org](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.OData/). See "[Create an OData v4 Endpoint Using ASP.NET Web API 2.2](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-v4/create-an-odata-v4-endpoint)" for more info.